# Enable crash dumps for non-packaged

Tags: crash, apport

We have an application *foo*, which I installed manually on a Ubuntu machine (packaging is not an option). *foo* is called from a script.
Now, when this application crashes, I do get an entry in `/var/crash`, but no core dump gets created.
So from reading up on this I did the following:

- Disabled *apport* (in `/etc/default/apport`).
- Disable system soft dump limit (`* soft core unlimited` to `/etc/security/limits.conf`)
- Put `ulimit -Sc unlimited` and `ulimit -Hc unlimited` before call to *foo*.

Still, I do not get a core dump (would expect it to appear in the same directory as `foo`).

Could someone please tell me, what I am missing.

Comment: Q1: What does your `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`  look like? This determines how kernel handles core dumps. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html. Do you still see  pipe to `apport` in your core pattern? If yes, then you need to understand what the `enable=0` in `/etc/default/apport` actually means to `apport`. And please, when finding the answer, do answer your own question, as this `apport` beast really seems badly documented.

Comment: Q2: Just to make sure, after setting limits, does `ulimit -Sc` show `unlimited` as output? I.e. did you verify that you really succeeded setting the limit at the time with the user account you were using.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you've gone about it the wrong way - by default, apport doesn't have to be disabled to handle unpackaged binaries, it will just log a few lines in its log file (/var/log/apport.log) and fall through to the default kernel behavior - write the core file to the current directory.

If this did not work for you, it probably wasn't about apport, it's more likely you didn't have some other prerequisite, such as the directory of `foo` not being writable to the user running the binary.